# How can I merge two audio tracks together in an AVI file?

Tags: audio, video, video-editing

I have an AVI file with two audio tracks that I am trying to edit.  When I open it in Media Player, it plays fine (I can hear both).  However, Windows Movie Maker and Adobe Premiere CS6 both seem to ignore the second audio track, and I can't find an option for multiple.  Is there a way I could combine them or make Premiere recognise that two exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ffprobe`, and `ffmpeg` tools. First, find out the numbers of the corresponding video, and audio streams using the `ffprobe` tool:

```
$ ffprobe video.avi
ffprobe version 3.2.10-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18) 20170516
...
Input #0, avi,webm, from 'video.avi':
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (DX50 / 0x30355844), yuv420p, 704x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 22:15], SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 44100 Hz, 5.1, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : 5.1 HE-AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : 2.0 Ogg Vorbis
```

In this case, we will want to retain the video stream 0:0 and mix the English, and Japanese audio streams 0:1, and 0:2 into a single audio stream. For this, we will use the `ffmpeg` tool with the [`amerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) audio filter:

```
$ ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i video.avi \
> -filter_complex '[0:1][0:2] amerge=inputs=2' \
> -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -q:a 128 video-converted.avi
```

Explanation of options:

- `-fflags +genpts` – We will not be re-encoding the video stream. However, if the video steam does not contain [filestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_timestamp), the muxer may refuse this with an error message. Regenerating just the timestamps fixes this without having to re-encode the entire video stream, which would be slow and unnecessary.
- `-i video.avi` – This specifies our input video file.
- `-filter_complex '[0:1][0:2] amerge=inputs=2'` – This tells the `amerge` filter to mix audio streams 0:1, and 0:2 into a single audio stream.
- `-c:v copy` – We will keep the original video stream without re-encoding.
- `-c:a aac -ac 2 -q:a 128` – We will encode the audio using the [AAC codec](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) with two channels and a bitrate of 128 kbps.
- `video-converted.avi` – This specifies our output video file.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the file into Audacity, verify that the tracks play as you wish there and then export the track into a file format that is flat and will play both tracks as one, for example .mp3.